# Last boolean flag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, boolean, flags

I have the following data structure which uses a flag to dynamically set the last item:

```
    var data = [
        {
            "id":"One",
            "last":false,    
        },
        {
            "id":"Two",
            "last":true,    
        },
        {
            "id":"Three",
            "last":false,    
        },
        {
            "id":"Four",
            "last":false,    
        },
        {
            "id":"Five",
            "last":false,    
        }
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log(data[i].id);
    }
```

How can I utilize the boolean so the code is outputted to the log in this order?

```
One
Three
Four
Five
Two
```

Answer (score 3):

You could sort the data by `last` property.

[`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is not necessary [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). In this case see below.

```js
var data = [{ id: "One", last: false }, { id: "Two", last: true }, { id: "Three", last: false }, { id: "Four", last: false }, { id: "Five", last: false }];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.last - b.last;
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or you could filter the array and concat both parts for `false` and `true` sub arrays.

```js
function last(flag) {
    return function (a) {
        return a.last === flag;
    };
}

var data = [{ id: "One", last: false }, { id: "Two", last: true }, { id: "Three", last: false }, { id: "Four", last: false }, { id: "Five", last: false }],
    temp = data.filter(last(false)).concat(data.filter(last(true)));

console.log(temp);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks. I went with your first suggestion and sorted the data first.

Answer (score 0):

Delare a new array

```
var newArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].last) {
         newArr.push(data[i]);
    } else {
      console.log(data[i].id);
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
   console.log(newArr[i].id);
}
```

JS FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/doptjgs2/

Comment: An array for one (the last) element?

Comment: There may be the case multiple elements should be printed last

Answer (score 0):

Well actually this is quite simply done in just O(n) by at least two methods. One is recursive (`falsesFirst` function below) and the other one is by `.reduceRight()` (`truesLast` function below);

```js
var data    = [{"id":"One","last":false},{"id":"Two","last":true},{"id":"Three","last":false},{"id":"Four","last":false},{"id":"Five","last":false}],
falsesFirst = d => d.length ? d[0].last ? falsesFirst(d.slice(1)).concat(d[0])
                                        : [d[0]].concat(falsesFirst(d.slice(1)))
                            : [],
  truesLast = d => d.reduceRight((r,o) => o.last ? r.concat(o) : [o].concat(r),[]);

console.log(falsesFirst(data));
console.log(truesLast(data));
```